# Rails model children of same type?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I'd like submissions to be able to have child submissions, or instances of the same model belonging to one. Also, there needs to be a "children" attribute in the submission JSON if the submission in question has child submissions. I need to be able to check through front-end JS. Here's my submission.rb file:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :folder
    belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Submission'
    has_many :children, :class_name => 'Submission', :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :order => ('updated_at DESC')


    attr_accessible :content, :title, :user_id, :folder_id, :parent_id

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
        else
            scoped
        end
    end

end
```

I've made some child submissions that belong to one parent submission through the `:parent_id` attribute, but I check the parent submission JSON and it looks like this:

```
{"content":"Test","created_at":"2013-09-02T01:18:06Z","folder_id":4,"id":176,"parent_id":null,"title":"Title test","updated_at":"2013-09-02T01:18:06Z","user_id":2}
```

As you can see, there's no `children` attribute showing the submissions that belong to this parent. In my Rails app I also have folders that can child folders, and I had no problem setting up that relationship. But this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe I answered a question from you about how to have the children recursively as json. What happen to that? Can't find the question either. Did you deleted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the problem with the Rails relationship or the json data being returned?

Does the relationship work in the rails console?  e.g.

```
Submission.find(176).children
```

And how are you rendering your json?  If you're using the default Rails json render you have to explicitly tell Rails which has_many relation you want to include, e.g.

```
render json: @submission.to_json(:include => :children)
```

I would highly recommend active_model_serializers if you're not using a json builder already (jbuilder, rabl, etc)

Comment: Yes, the relationship works in my Rails console, and I'm rendering the children through Rails .erb. It works and displays the children fine. The problem is that since the children aren't displayed in the JSON data itself, I can't check for children in my JS on the front-end. I have to take different actions based on whether or not a submission has children.

Comment: I'm using a framework called D3 on the front-end, and I have to give D3 the JSON data.

Comment: But how are you rendering the json from your controller?  If you're not using a json builder (rabl, jbuilder, active_model_serializers) you need to explicitly include the has_many in the json render call in your respond_to block... e.g.  format.json { render json: @submission.to_json(:include => :children) }